# how to write the two echo statement to output.txt file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have written a script that counts a number of tabs and number of lines in a given file.but i want to print the output to text file.how to do that?

here is what i have tried,but i am not able to print both in output.txt file

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
FILE='units.txt'
TABCOUNT=$(tr -cd '\t' < $FILE  | wc -c)
LINECOUNT=$(wc -l < $FILE)
echo $LINECOUNT "lines in file" $FILE > output.txt 
echo $TABCOUNT "tabs in file" $FILE > output.txt
echo "Done!"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `>>` instead of `>`.

`>` truncates the file, effectively overwriting it with new content.

`>>` appends content to the end of the file.